# How to make nsurlsessiond actions less anonymous to the user?

Tags: macos, network, high-sierra

With the introduction of OS X Yosemite every once in a while little snitch (network monitoring program) pops up a requestor asking for permission to allow nsurlsessiond a connection to some ip address.

I understand that nsurlsessiond provides an API to allow any program using it to retrieve data via http or other supported protocol. In fact it acts like a proxy.

Is it possible to see which programs are using nsurlsessiond and of course what they use it for?  I'm thinking of something like an access log file. Because in this current situation I am not able to do monitoring on applications using nsurlsessiond.

Answer (score 4):

The 'more details' button should at least tell you who it's trying to contact, from which you may be able to decide whether to allow.

Possibly the main connections floater would give you more data…

[image]

You could always drop in a request to [obdev](https://www.obdev.at/index.html) or even see if there's anything in the [forum](http://forums.obdev.at/viewforum.php?f=1&sid=f316e94c5fb06cc500aa76715b1d0c4a)

I agree it would be a useful addition, to know what app is calling an API like that.

Comment: ObDev forum topic https://forums.obdev.at/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=9411

Comment: @eskatos - the OP starts well... from there it rapidly goes downhill, into several foaming, truly witless rants along the lines of "I enabled iCloud sync & now iCloud is syncing... how to stop it!!" Let's hope your post returns it to its former sensibilities ;)

Comment: Yup :) Those that must attract attention are the folks of ObDev. Let see how it goes.

Comment: This API should have never made it to production! As far as I'm concerned, it's a serious security flaw. For example, if an app is trying to access my Google Drive then I'd like to know that I intended that app to have such access. I'm surprised that (effectively) anonymous requests are permitted at all.

Answer (score 3):

The `nsurlsessiond` cache is at `~/Library/com.apple.nsurlsessiond` and you can check the various configuration.plist and tasks.plist files to see which apps have active sessions.

Answer (score 1):

In System Preferences turn off "automatically check for updates" and "download newly available updates in the background" in the App Store Preferences

Comment: This question is not about disabling but on monitoring nsurlsessiond. Besides as I wrote in my question any program may use the API.